# Can someone explain how to select the proper random effect when analyzing a split plot design in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, split-plot

I am struggling to understand the concept of assigning the random effect when using a mixed linear model to analyze my **split-plot** experiment in R.

Below is the data I am working with. This should create a data frame when pasted into R:

```
data <- data.frame(plot = c(101,
                            102,
                            103,
                            104,
                            105,
                            106,
                            107,
                            108,
                            109,
                            110,
                            111,
                            112,
                            113,
                            114,
                            115,
                            116,
                            117,
                            118,
                            119,
                            120,
                            121,
                            122,
                            123,
                            124,
                            125,
                            126,
                            127,
                            128,
                            129,
                            130,
                            131,
                            132,
                            133,
                            134,
                            135,
                            136,
                            137,
                            138,
                            139,
                            140,
                            141,
                            142,
                            143,
                            144,
                            145,
                            146,
                            147,
                            148,
                            149,
                            150,
                            151,
                            152,
                            153,
                            154,
                            155,
                            156,
                            157,
                            158,
                            159,
                            160),
                   block = c(1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3),
                   crop = c('corn',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'canola',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'soybeans',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'wheat',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'corn',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers',
                            'sunflowers'),
                   fertilizer = c(1,
                                  2,
                                  3,
                                  4,
                                  4,
                                  3,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  3,
                                  1,
                                  4,
                                  4,
                                  3,
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  4,
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  3,
                                  2,
                                  3,
                                  4,
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  3,
                                  4,
                                  4,
                                  3,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  3,
                                  4,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  4,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  3,
                                  2,
                                  3,
                                  1,
                                  4,
                                  4,
                                  3,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  3,
                                  4,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  3,
                                  4,
                                  2,
                                  1,
                                  3,
                                  4),
                   growth = c(52,
                              36,
                              40,
                              39,
                              50,
                              28,
                              21,
                              31,
                              46,
                              32,
                              27,
                              32,
                              35,
                              26,
                              36,
                              22,
                              37,
                              46,
                              29,
                              21,
                              20,
                              31,
                              31,
                              46,
                              31,
                              38,
                              30,
                              34,
                              54,
                              54,
                              37,
                              35,
                              40,
                              46,
                              28,
                              41,
                              54,
                              51,
                              53,
                              33,
                              33,
                              48,
                              51,
                              29,
                              30,
                              51,
                              44,
                              53,
                              49,
                              27,
                              28,
                              29,
                              22,
                              34,
                              25,
                              26,
                              50,
                              49,
                              28,
                              37))
```

The experiment is laid out so that the main plot factor (crop) is divided up into 4 sub-plot factors (fertilizer type). I have three replicates (or blocks) of each experiment. One replicate looks like this (let's pretend the fertilizer is randomized):

[image]

I wish to determine the effect of crop and fertilizer (independent variables) on growth (dependent variable). Here is what I have done so far:

```
library(car)
library(lmerTest)
library(lme4)

data$block <- as.factor(data$block)
data$crop <- as.factor(data$crop)
data$fertilizer <- as.factor(data$fertilizer)

mod <- lmer(growth ~ crop * fertilizer + (1|block/crop), data = data)
Anova(mod, type = c("II"))
```

In this case, I am not worried about the warning that is thrown (`boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')`) because this is a synthetic dataset.

**My question is regarding the specification of the random effect**: Most of the sources say that when using a random effect model to analyze a split-plot design such as this one, the proper specification of the random effect is to put the treatment block over the main plot factor, as I have done above: `(1|block/crop)`.

Why would one do this, and what exactly is this random effect telling you? I am familiar with the ANOVA table for split-plot designs, but I'm still struggling to understand what the random effect exactly is.

Note: I know that one could use the `agricolae` package to simplify this analysis, but I am needing to use a random effects model for several reasons.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/d57cb617d54be10d5a8cc344e2f3d3cd) is a Python gist converting a string of your dataframe instantiation to a `pandas` dataframe using `rpy2`.